# Please explain me the difference between two ways to calculate a time when something with a probability of P will happen

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's take a look at an example:(taken from the brilliant.org course on probability )
Given a chance for failure to happen in any month is 12.6%
There are 2 ways to calculate the T (time, or months amount to be more precise)

1. The first way is presented on brilliant.org. they suggest the formula T=1/p
   meaning that 1/0.126 = 7.9 months
2. I knew another way, but maybe I was wrong. The way I was familiar with is:

*The chance the failure does not happen in the first month is 1-0.126=0.87*

*The chance it will ALSO not happen in the second month is 0.87 * 0.87 =0.87^2 = 0.76*

*The chance it will ALSO not happen in the third month is 0.87 * 0.87 * 0.87 =0.87^3 = 0.67*

and so on.(see the image attached)
[image]

Yes, I know that the second method instead gives a probability something to happen in any month than giving the specific month when the failure is likely to happen, which does the 1/p formula
but I  will be glad to understand why the formula gives me month 8 where the probability not to happen is 30.4%. It sounds much better if the formula would return a month where the probability is, let us say, below 5%.

Thank you very much.

Comment: $~T = 1/p~$ is equal to the **expected** time before a success occurs.  This means that if you are considering a time interval of $~n,~$ then the expected number of successes in this interval is $~\dfrac{n}{T} = np.~$  Your alternate computation expresses the idea that the probability that there is **at least** one success in the first $~n~$ time intervals is $~1 - (1-p)^n.$ There is no contradiction here.    ...see next comment

Comment: This is because computing the **expected** number of successes in a time interval of $~n~$ is different from computing the probability of **at least one success** in $~n~$ time intervals.  That is, the *phrase* "at least one success" includes the *events* when there is more than one success.

Comment: As a clarifying illustration, suppose that you are given the following information.  In a certain time interval, there will either be $~0,1,$ or $~2~$ successes.  Further suppose that the probability of these mutually exclusive events is $~0.4, 0.3, ~$ and $~0.3,~$ respectively.  Then, the probability of at least one success in this interval is $~1 - 0.4 = 0.6.~$  Further, the expected number of successes in this interval will be $$(0 \times 0.4) + (1 \times 0.3) + (2 \times 0.3) = 0.9.$$

Comment: "giving the specific month when the failure is likely to happen" Warning! The failure 
 is _not_ "more likely" to happen in the month given by "Brilliant". The failure is equally (un)likely to happen in any month. This number only means the following:

Suppose you have a very large amount of factories/people doing this thing. Then for each factory, write down the month that failure happens. Then average all these month numbers. You end up with "Brilliant"s answer.

But this is _not_ "more likely", only the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say chance of failure is $p$.

We want to calculate the expected value of the month that failure happens (Call this $F_i$ for failure happening in month $i$).

This is given by:

$$1\cdot P(F_1)+2\cdot P(F_2)+3\cdot P(F_3)+\dots$$$$=1\cdot p+2\cdot(1-p)\cdot p+3\cdot(1-p)^2\cdot p+\dots$$$$=p\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}\right)$$

Solving this sum (e.g. [using wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+k+%281-p%29%5E%28k-1%29+from+k%3D1+to+infinity) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence)) we obtain that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(1-p)^{k-1}=\frac1{p^2}$$ and thus this average is equal to $\frac1p$. This includes *both* your formulas *and* the equation that "Brilliant" grabbed from thin air.

> It sounds much better if the formula would return a month where the probability is, let us say, below 5%.

If the probability is below 5%, say day 25, then it is "very likely" that failure will have happened. This means that if I do this experiment many times (Say I buy some equipment every time it breaks and write down how many months that takes each time), then it is *almost always* before day 25. So day 25 is an over-estimate of the *average* number of days it takes.